# Java noob, wondering if I made a mistake regarding packages

Tags: java, package

So to give context, I am new to Java and have no other programming experience. The IDE I am using is NetBeans. I picked up a book called "Sams Teach Yourself Java" and the tutorials in this book are having me put all the different classes I write in the same package. The problem with this is that when I want to run a class with attached arguments I can't just run the file from the "Run" tab. The book tells me to run it as a main project. But if I select run as main, one of my other classes runs. I figured out a work-around buy setting a main class, but I haven't found anything online about this and want to make sure I am not doing something stupid. This is my first question and any tips on how to ask effective questions on this site are appreciated.

Comment: You can run any class with a `main()` via a right-click in the souce code window.

Comment: So I guess my question is, why would the author of the book expect the reader to be able to run this code with attached arguments if it can't be run as a main project because of the presence of other classes in the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While learning, there is nothing wrong with putting many classes in the same package. The reasons for separating classes into different packages can wait until later lessons and learning.

You can run a particular class as a Java application in Netbeans, assuming it has the correct `main()` method, by pressing ctrl-shift-f5 while that class is the one currently selected (i.e., currently displayed in the editor pane). You can run the most recently run java application by pressing ctrl-f5, even if that class is not the one currently selected.

This question is clear enough. If you get to a programming problem, go far enough to have tried something that doesn't work as expected. To ask about it, try to show the smallest program that illustrates your problem; tell WHAT is happening that you do not expect (or not happening that you do). If there is an error message, include all of it, don't just describe it.

Comment: Just a note about StackOverflow -- the 'up' and 'down' indicators are used to indicate whether an answer was or was not useful to you, whether or not you asked the question. Feel free to upvote ANY question that is useful to you, it gives points to the people who volunteer their time to answer questions, and is part of how the whole site works.

Comment: Ok, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is each class a new project/example from the book?

You could have multiple classes within the same package that each have a main method. Only the main method within the class that is selected to run/passed on will be called.

In NetBeans, there is a little drop down arrow that you can press and it should allow you to specify which one to call.

Answer (score 0):

The application is running properly. That I can assure you. Since all the classes you created contains main method the compiler is confused because it does not know which class's main method should be executed successfully. Hence, it builds all the methods but does not execute them. If you observe the output tab, after clicking on the run button, it will always show build successful. This means it it building the classes but not executing them. To execute each class separately, either right-click on the class and then select the run option, or use the keyboard shortcut 'Shift+F6'. This shortcut executes the class you are currently working in.